# Why the SelectCheckboxMenu + Map<Integer,List<Integer>> just turn the value inside the variable?

Tags: jsf, generics, primefaces, classcastexception, selectcheckboxmenu

When I set the variable in my bean, the conversion is OK. Look the variables in the Image:

[Without Conversion Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtq9q.png)

When I use xhtml to set a variable, UI:repeat + p:selectCheckboxMenu I received this error:

```
 /* Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List */
```

Look the variables:

[With conversion Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1C30.png)

In my JSF I have:

```
<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{bean.questions}">
 <p:selectCheckboxMenu converter="javax.faces.Integer" filter="true" 
    value="#{bean.selectedDinamicRoadmap[q.id]}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.roadmaps}" var="roadm" itemLabel="#{roadm.description} " itemValue="#{roadm.id}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</ui:repeat>
```

And in my bean I need save a selectedDinamicRoadmap[] And look my code for this:

```
private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> selectedDinamicRoadmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
//gets and sets
public void save() {
 for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> ee : selectedDinamicRoadmap.entrySet()) {
  Integer key = ee.getKey();
  List<Integer> values = ee.getValue();  /* Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List */
  for (Integer id : values) {
   //saveData
  }
 }
}
```

how could I fix this? Or what`s the best solution for this?

I have tried:

```
List<Integer> values = ee.getValue(); 
List<String> values = ee.getValue(); 
Integer[] values = ee.getValue();
String[] values = ee.getValue();  
Object[] values = ee.getValue();// <- It is working : WHY?
```

of course changing the necessary code.

Comment: The error means that the map actually contains string arrays instead of string lists as values.

Comment: When I try this: String[] values = ee.getValue(); Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to String[]

Comment: Ofcourse, because you have a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`. But somehow you did something type unsafe (or something else than your own code did) and you have a wrong type of object as the value in the map.

Comment: I turn the solution as @BalusC suggested, but it isn`t worked

Comment: 'isn't worked' is to vague, please be more specific

Comment: @Kukeltje, I am sorry, I received this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection  in this line: items.addAll(entry.getValue()); I changed the code as a sample with the error

Comment: @Kukeltje, you have some idea? When I use **String[] values = ee.getValue()** I received : **Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to String[]** You know where I learn about that conversions?